# dnf update - dependencies

Tags: update, dependencies, dnf

During update I've encountered following errors

```
yum update
Last metadata expiration check: 0:44:43 ago on Mon 11 Apr 2022 06:33:55 AM CEST.
Error:
 Problem 1: package containers-common-2:1-23.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64 requires runc, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1:1.0.3-3.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64
  - installed package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1:1.0.3-3.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64
  - package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module_el8.5.0+733+9bb5dffa.x86_64
  - installed package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module_el8.5.0+733+9bb5dffa.x86_64
  - package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.5.0+911+f19012f9.x86_64
  - installed package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.5.0+911+f19012f9.x86_64
  - package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+878+851f435b.x86_64
  - installed package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+878+851f435b.x86_64
  - package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64
  - installed package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64
  - package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.6.0+926+8bef8ae7.x86_64
  - installed package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.6.0+926+8bef8ae7.x86_64
  - package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-3.module_el8.5.0+870+f792de72.x86_64
  - installed package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-3.module_el8.5.0+870+f792de72.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package containers-common-1:1.2.2-4.module_el8.5.0+733+9bb5dffa.x86_64
  - problem with installed package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64
  - package runc-1.0.0-64.rc10.module_el8.4.0+522+66908d0c.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package runc-1.0.0-73.rc95.module_el8.6.0+1107+d59a301b.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package runc-1.0.0-56.rc5.dev.git2abd837.module_el8.4.0+521+9df8e6d3.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module_el8.5.0+736+58cc1a5a.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package runc-1:1.0.3-1.module_el8.6.0+1108+b13568aa.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
 Problem 2: package skopeo-2:1.6.1-1.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64 requires containers-common >= 2:1-2, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package containers-common-2:1-2.module_el8.6.0+926+8bef8ae7.noarch requires runc, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package containers-common-2:1-2.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.noarch requires runc, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package containers-common-2:1-23.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64 requires runc, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package containers-common-2:1-4.module_el8.6.0+944+d413f95e.noarch requires runc, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package containers-common-2:1-6.module_el8.6.0+954+963caf36.noarch requires runc, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1:1.0.3-3.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64
  - installed package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1:1.0.3-3.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64
  - package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module_el8.5.0+733+9bb5dffa.x86_64
  - installed package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module_el8.5.0+733+9bb5dffa.x86_64
  - package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.5.0+911+f19012f9.x86_64
  - installed package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.5.0+911+f19012f9.x86_64
  - package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+878+851f435b.x86_64
  - installed package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+878+851f435b.x86_64
  - package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64
  - installed package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-5.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64
  - package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.6.0+926+8bef8ae7.x86_64
  - installed package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.2-1.module_el8.6.0+926+8bef8ae7.x86_64
  - package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with runc provided by runc-1.0.1-3.module_el8.5.0+870+f792de72.x86_64
  - installed package containerd.io-1.4.11-3.1.el8.x86_64 obsoletes runc provided by runc-1.0.1-3.module_el8.5.0+870+f792de72.x86_64
  - package docker-ce-3:20.10.9-3.el8.x86_64 requires containerd.io >= 1.4.1, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package skopeo-1:1.4.0-6.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64
  - problem with installed package docker-ce-3:20.10.9-3.el8.x86_64
  - package containers-common-2:1-19.module_el8.6.0+1108+b13568aa.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package runc-1.0.0-64.rc10.module_el8.4.0+522+66908d0c.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package runc-1.0.0-73.rc95.module_el8.6.0+1107+d59a301b.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package runc-1.0.0-56.rc5.dev.git2abd837.module_el8.4.0+521+9df8e6d3.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package runc-1.0.0-70.rc92.module_el8.5.0+736+58cc1a5a.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
  - package runc-1:1.0.3-1.module_el8.6.0+1108+b13568aa.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
(try to add '--allowerasing' to command line to replace conflicting packages or '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

How to solve such errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove the problematic package:

```
dnf remove -y containers-common-2:1-23.module_el8.7.0+1106+45480ee0.x86_64
```

And then:

```
dnf clean all && dnf check && dnf check-update
```

Followed by:

```
dnf update -y && dnf upgrade -y
```

Comment: That's defying the purpose if you actually need the containers-common pckage